# What differences are there between labelling options that appear under /dev/disk/by-label and /dev/disk/by-partlabel?

Tags: linux, partition, coreos

I want to create a disk under CoreOS that is automatically mounted at /var/lib/docker

So I created a var-lib-docker.mount unit file to do it and decided to use the by-label path under /dev/disk.

Initially I found my partitions appear under the by-partlabel path.
It works great however.

In the process I found out that there is a program called e2label, and also under fdisk expert mode I can also create a partition label.

Having not found e2label initially I found I could label partitions with the word "DOCKER" in fdisk.  But they actually come through to the path /dev/disk/by-partlabel and not /dev/disk/by-label

What are the differences between these? should one be favoured over the other?

Comment: Don't know why people think it's an off topic question when this is about partitioning on servers in a server farm.  anyway....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArchLinux wiki has (as always) good [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming#Persistent_naming_methods) on this issue. You wrote:

> Having not found e2label initially I found I could label partitions 
>   with the word "DOCKER" in fdisk. But they actually come through to the
>   path /dev/disk/by-label

I assume you meant "do NOT come through"? That could be explained by the fact that you created a *partition* label and your labeled disk should show up under `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/` instead. Once you create a *filesystem* label (e.g. via `e2label` (`tune2fs -L`) for ext{2,3,4} file systems), the disk should show up under `/dev/disk/by-label`.

> should one be favoured over the other?

*partition* labels are only available for [GPT disks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming#by-partlabel). For *filesystem* labels one would need some filesystem tool to apply a label to the partition. All major on-disk file systems seem to have this (`tune2fs -L`, `jfs_tune -L`, `xfs_admin -L`, `reiserfstune -l`) so unless it's something more exotic, file system labels should work just fine.

Comment: Right that makes sense.  I'm using GPT labels and so they appear as partlabel.  Old filesystem labels appear as by-label and is a feature of the filesystem.  Thanks for the explanation!